# Should every method return a value for Unit Testing?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I am learning to create simple Unit tests to eventually (and hopefully) start to do only TDD; for now I am trying to write tests for code already written to see what might cause problems. This is one of them.

Let's say I have this simple class (with Typescript-> Javascript):

```js
class PrivateStuff {
    greeting: string;
    private _thisIsPrivate;

    constructor(isPrivate: boolean) {
        this._thisIsPrivate = isPrivate;
    }

    setPrivate(option) {
        this._thisIsPrivate = option;
        console.log("_thisIsPrivate changed to : " + option);
    }

    getPrivate() {
        console.log("_thisIsPrivate is : " + this._thisIsPrivate);
        return this._thisIsPrivate;        
    }
}
```

And I use it in this way:

```js
let privateStuff = new PrivateStuff(false);

let buttonSet = document.createElement('button');
buttonSet.textContent = "Set True";
buttonSet.onclick = function () {
    privateStuff.setPrivate(true);
}

let buttonGet = document.createElement('button');
buttonGet.textContent = "Get";
buttonGet.onclick = function() {
    console.log(privateStuff.getPrivate());
}
document.body.appendChild(buttonSet);
document.body.appendChild(buttonGet);
```

`setPrivate()` does not need to return anything, but because of that I cannot test it.  When creating a unit test for it, should I refactor the code?

If I were doing TDD, should I always create methods that return something just to be able to test it?  Or I am missing something?

P.S. You can see and run the code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20PrivateStuff%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20greeting%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20_thisIsPrivate%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(isPrivate%3A%20boolean)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._thisIsPrivate%20%3D%20isPrivate%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20setPrivate(option)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._thisIsPrivate%20%3D%20option%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22_thisIsPrivate%20changed%20to%20%3A%20%22%20%2B%20option)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20getPrivate()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22_thisIsPrivate%20is%20%3A%20%22%20%2B%20this._thisIsPrivate)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._thisIsPrivate%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20privateStuff%20%3D%20new%20PrivateStuff(false)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20buttonSet%20%3D%20document.createElement(%27button%27)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20buttonSet.textContent%20%3D%20%22Set%20True%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20buttonSet.onclick%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20privateStuff.setPrivate(true)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20buttonGet%20%3D%20document.createElement(%27button%27)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20buttonGet.textContent%20%3D%20%22Get%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20buttonGet.onclick%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(privateStuff.getPrivate())%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20document.body.appendChild(buttonSet)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20document.body.appendChild(buttonGet)%3B)

Comment: If you setPrivate wouldn't the value of getPrivate tell you if it worked?

Comment: @JeffO yes, I see now that I do no *just* have to use the function's return to check if it worked.

Comment: "setPrivate() does not need to return anything, but because of that I cannot test it." Does it induce any observable effect? If so, you can test it. Otherwise, there is no interest in testing it (and there is no interest in implement it).

Comment: @mgoeminne What if the method is void and writes to the database/log or sends a message to another object as its only effect?

Comment: @AndresF. You can read from the database/log or mock the other object to confirm that the data was sent. It may not be a "unit" test, but that's not what actually matters.

Comment: @JacobRaihle If you read from the database you're no longer unit testing. If you mock the other object, that also has problems (some people object to mocks at all).  In either case, it's no longer black box testing, which a lot of practitioners advocate.The point is: there is no clear-cut answer. Void/Unit methods are indeed problematic for unit testing.

Comment: @AndresF. If you're *writing* to the database you're no longer unit testing. But so what?

Comment: @JacobRaihle You're confusing the *subject under test* with the test itself -- a unit test is never defined by what the *SUT* does. A void/unit method is by definition a side-effecting method. The original question is about unit testing this. The comment (and current answer) imply there is an easy solution, but as I pointed out, there isn't.

Comment: @AndresF. But it *is* partially defined by how much infrastructure you need to set up around the subject for it to work, and a database is typically considered too much for a unit test. Thus I agree that it cannot be "unit" tested, but it can certainly still be tested (which is all the original comment said).

Comment: @JacobRaihle I know it can be tested. But the question was about *unit* testing, therefore the comment was not entirely on-topic :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I guess your misconception here is that a *"subject under test"* must be always a method on its own. But that is not true, though some methods can be tested without using any other methods, the typical size of a SUT is a class, or some interacting methods and functions of one class. So if you have a method which changes the internal state of an object, there must be *always* some externally visible change to the behaviour of that object (otherwise it would not make any sense to have the method in the first place). And in a unit test, you can validate exactly this behaviour.

For example, lets say you have a class `NumberFormatter` with a responsibility to format floating point numbers in a predefined way. Lets assume it contains a method `FormatToString(double d)`. Let's further assume it has a method `setDecimalSeparator`, but no `getDecimalSeparator`. Nethertheless you can easily write a test if after a call to `setDecimalSeparator` the method `FormatToString` behaves in a desired way. Such a test could look like this

```
  var nf = new NumberFormatter();
  nf.setDecimalSeparator(".");
  AssertEqual("12.34",nf.FormatToString(12.34))
  nf.setDecimalSeparator(",");
  AssertEqual("12,34",nf.FormatToString(12.34))
```

So this is a meaningful test of `setDecimalSeparator`, a method without a return value.

Comment: I see, so in my unrealistic example I could use the ´getPrivate()´  function to see if ´_thisIsPrivate´ had change and muss asume that ´getPrivate()´ works but in a more real case scenario should I test the object being changed. Thank you for your clear explanation!